# ESPAsyncWebServer.h with esp32

Tags: esp32

I am new to esp32 programming. I wanted to try to make a server.

I tried to use the [ESPAsyncWebServer library](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/tree/master/src).

I got this error

> ```
> In file included from C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\server\server.ino:2:0:
>
> Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
> sketch\ESPAsyncWebServer.h:33:22: fatal error: AsyncTCP.h: No such file or directory
>
> Used: C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\WiFi
> compilation terminated.
>
> Not used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.33.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\WiFi
> exit status 1
> Error compiling for board ESP32 Wrover Module.
> ```

Can someone help me and tell me what is the correct way to install liberals because I have a feeling that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I advise you to use VS Code and PlatformIO IDE for ESP32 and ESP8266, the below link will help you https://randomnerdtutorials.com/vs-code-platformio-ide-esp32-esp8266-arduino/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compile error says that you are lacking the AsyncTCP library. You can find it here: https://github.com/me-no-dev/AsyncTCP

Answer (score 3):

You will need to install both libraries ESPAsyncTCP and ESPAsyncWebServer, since the latter is dependant on the first.

You can install them by:

1. Downloading the zip files from github:

   - https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer
   - https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncTCP
2. In your Arduino IDE go to `Sketch > Include Library > ZIP-Library` and select the libraries you just downloaded.